# Linux user ssh connection disabled after execution of setfacl command

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, users

I have very little linux administration experience, after searching a lot stuff online, finally I decided that I must hope that someone helps.

The problem is, I needed to share an account with a customer to access to specific directory of my CentOS Linux server (FTP).

After creation of user with `useradd` command, I executed `setfacl` commands as follows.

```
setfacl -m user:abc:0 /opt
setfacl -m user:abc:0 /bin
setfacl -m user:abc:0 /boot
setfacl -m user:abc:0 /srv
setfacl -m user:abc:0 /usr
```

Now, I cannot open ssh connection via a non-root user. (Using putty, after entering username-password, window dissappears.)

I tried to delete the abc user and created a new one, but problem continues.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I do not think setfacl is the right approach if you want incoming ssh for user abc over ssh. You need to make sure the sshd is working on this machine and is configured for a non-root user to accept connections. Lookup web with these keywords: sshd allow user config.

Comment: Thank you, I will. is there a way to redo these executed setfacl command?

Comment: If you mean undo, you can use `-d` switch in place of `-m` and run the same commands again.